# Book or series about a group of teens in a space colony who discover telepathic creatures

Tags: story-identification, novel, telepathy, space-colonization

I have been trying to find this series that I read in grade school. Some of the info I remember is:

1. They have hover technology, hover bikes that the kids hack to remove safety restraints, and hover transports to move goods from settlement to settlement.
2. I think 1 character was named Philippa, but called Pippa (I think) and she had a criminal past.
3. The “creatures” they discover use telepathic communication, and it changes the teens so they can kind of communicate with each other.
4. 1 of the group of teens may have been from a planet with heavy gravity…I’m not positive on this point.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this, and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: I likely read the series in 1988-1992…about. 
I think one of the covers was looking over a couple of teens shoulders looking towards a mountain.

Comment: I vaguely remember reading a similar book, but it's from the last 15 years, and I don't remember anyone named Philippa or Pippa. Are you sure about Philippa and the date?

Comment: I’m not positive about the character name, but that seems to have stuck. However I’m positive it was whole I was in high school…and I graduated in 1995. So it was before that. What series are you thinking of, maybe they redid it?